# Wifi Printer with Apple Time Capsule

Tags: wifi, printing, time-capsule

I have connected my wired printer with Time Capsule in order to use it as a Wi-Fi printer.

This setup works very well with my MacBook, but my Windows PC on same network is unable to locate the Wi-Fi printer.

I've tried everything listed on the Internet to add it as a network printer, but nothing has worked.

Can someone please advice how I can print to the Wi-Fi printer using Windows as well?

Comment: What model is the printer? What network protocols does it offer?

Comment: Did you install/enable Bonjour for Windows?

Comment: @Allan Bonjour for windows is enabled, i have verified it.

Comment: @benwiggy I am using Brother printer : Brother HL-L2321D, I believe it offers all normal protocols.